# ld can't find crti.o when trying to build libgcc for arm-unknown-linux-gnuabi

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, arm64

I'm currently trying to build a cross compiler toolchain to compile the linux kernel for aarch64 and everything worked fine until I tried building libgcc.

When running `make all-target-libgcc` I get the error `/opt/cross/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: no such file or directory`. Same goes for 'crtn.o' and '-lc'.
I've searched the /opt/cross/lib dir for the files and could not find them, but I did come across the unassembled .S files in the gcc source directory (crti.S, ....).

The binaries also exist in /usr/lib but I'm assuming that's irrelevant since those are x86-64.

What I'm wondering now is why the .S files in the gcc source dir (version 10.1.x) weren't assembled into binaries and how I could change that.

Thank you in advance for any help

PS: I've found a similar post here on stack overflow about crti.o missing but that was unhelpful.

Comment: I tried assembling it with ```/opt/cross/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-as /.../aarch64/crti.S``` but I got an error " Error: bad instruction `type(_init)' "

Comment: How to decide a package, when "file" is known: Use `apt-file search crti.o` ..... or use the on-line search https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=crti.o

Answer (score 0):

Seems my research was rather bad, you don't actually need glibc / libgcc to cross compile the linux kernel.
I found this article which was very helpful if anyone is having a similar problem: https://gts3.org/2017/cross-kernel.html